# How to edit previously created excel workbook with python ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, writer

I have a few data frames that I made which I then added to an excel spreadsheet created in the program with this snippet of code.

```
writer = ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
stats.to_excel(writer,'ELO')
pdf.to_excel(writer,'Playoffs')
sec.to_excel(writer,'Second Round')
cf.to_excel(writer,'Conference Finals')
cham.to_excel(writer,'Finals')
df.to_excel(writer,'Stanley Cup Winner')
writer.save()
```

This code creates an excel sheet and adds these pages to it...The problem is that I update the data frames every week, and when I re-run the program, I get this error--

FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xlsx'

It seems I can't edit the workbook/add to it.

Is there any way I can do this, and add updated pages to go along with the ones that were already put in?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you do not close the `ExcelWriter`, it does not let you write to it again. Add `writer.close()` in the last line and it should work.

Comment: How do you close it?

Comment: it still tells me "permission denied"